# Socket.io socket property not found in disconnect event, node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a small but annoying problem that I can't find the solution for.

On the server side I have this:

```
...
socket.on('join', function (name) 
{
    console.log("Joining: "+name);
    socket.userName = sanitize(name);
}
socket.on('msg', function(m)
{
    console.log(socket.userName+" says: "+m);//This works
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(socket) 
{
    console.log(socket.userName+" has disconnected");//This does not work  
});
...
```

The issue is that the `socket.userName` is available in all my `.on` methods **exept** for `socket.on('disconnect',...`

I get `undefined` for the userName property.

---

Is this simply not possible to do? If this is not best pratcie, please let me know. I am farily new to node.js

Comment: Found the error now. How did I not see this? I have `socket` as input variable, which is not the same thing as the socket I want to access...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `disconnect` event is passed an argument, so you're effectively clobbering your `socket` variable. Just use an empty argument list for its handler:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() 
{
  console.log(socket.userName+" has disconnected");
});
```

Comment: Just realized myself. Thanks