# How to bind property to socket object using deployd?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, deployd

I don't even know if that question makes sense. I don't have a lot of experience with socket.io or deployd. You'll probably understand what I'm trying to do from my code. It's similar to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910213/socket-io-socket-property-not-found-in-disconnect-event-node-js) Here is my server code.

```
var deployd = require('deployd');

var options = {
  //options go here
};

var dpd = deployd(options);

dpd.listen();

dpd.on('getLobby', function (lobby) {
    dpd.lobby = lobby; //trying to bind variable to socket
    console.log('get Lobby');
});

dpd.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log("disconnected");
});

dpd.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('connection');
});
```

and on my client side I have this

```
dpd.socket.emit('getLobby', lobby, function (data) {
    console.log("emitted");
    console.log(data); 
});
```

The server works. My app works. Everything runs fine except for this code. I get no errors and no console logs. None of this code seems to work at all. It doesn't seem to emit and it doesn't seem to catch an emission if there even is one. I have tried lots of different ways of writing this.